# Getting Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest' error on Bot Framework to Facebook Azure channel

Tags: azure, bots, botframework

I am getting below error while I am sending response back to my Facebook channel using Azure Bot service. I used bot framework 4.0

One or more errors occurred. (Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'

I getting above error while calling below methods

```
Task t = Task.Run(() => turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Hi hellow", "Hi hellow", InputHints.AcceptingInput), cancellationToken), cancellationToken); 
t.Wait(cancellationToken);
await Task.CompletedTask;
```

and also

```
Task t = Task.Run(() => turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Attachment(card?.ToAttachment(), ssml: ssml), cancellationToken), cancellationToken);
t.Wait(cancellationToken); 
await Task.CompletedTask;
```

the card object have below values

```
{
   "title":"",
   "subtitle":"",
   "text":"For the best experience you should log in to your My Choice account.",
   "images":null,
   "buttons":[
      {
         "type":"postBack",
         "title":"Let's Get Started",
         "image":null,
         "text":"Let's get started",
         "displayText":"Let's get started",
         "value":"Let's get started",
         "channelData":null,
         "imageAltText":null
      }
   ],
```

"tap":null
}

Comment: It is possible that there is a problem with the card object you are passing, such as missing or invalid values for the title, subtitle, text, or buttons properties.

Comment: Is your bot works in web chat?